# Is it viable connection string?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DATABASE1;Integrated Security=True
```

The above is my connection string.

Now my question is: Is it viable connection string considering that the application will be deployed to a client's computer without any remote connection at all. Everything on the same client's computer. Is there anything I have to do on the connection string for this to be possible?

Comment: As long as the data source is the same, and the catalog exists in the data source, and your queries obviously target the same tables and columns, it'll work - no reason not to.

Comment: Will the client also be installing SqlExpress?  It might be better to use something like Sqlite as your back end database as that allows the database files localtion to be specified in the connection string.

Comment: A simple test will answer your question. FYI, everyone who logs into the computer will be able to access the database.

Comment: The connection string **MUST** be configurable at the deployment site, so you don't force them to replicate your environment. It'll work as long as there is an installation of a named instance of SQL Server named "SQLEXPRESS", but it's much better if it can work with any other instance instead.

Comment: Neil I am not for SqLite or SQLCE due to some limitations in queries

Comment: Alejandro..So it means the connection string is just fine only that the client's machine must have "SQLEXPRESS" instance of SQL installed?..This may sound silly but let me just ask... How will the SQL instance attach the database???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as the SQL Server instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`.

Note, though, that other software might be installed on your client's machine as well, and that this other software might *also* install an SQL Server instance with the instance name `SQLEXPRESS`. If this instance is a different SQL Server version than the one you require for your application, you have a problem.

Thus, my suggestion is to use a more unique SQL Server instance name (for example, containing your company or product name) instead. Obviously, allowing the user to configure or override the connection string (or at least the instance name) will avoid that problem altogether.

Comment: Now Heinzi, your first line of the statement has encouraged me...now let me depend on your first statement. Then this brings me to this question: How will the SQLEXPRESS Server instance find the database, because my connection string does not contain key words "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|".......Clarify a bit

Comment: @Calvinceokeyo: Well, when you install your application on your client's machine, you will also have to install SQL Server Express and *attach* the database to your SQL Server Express Instance (for example, using SQL Server Management Studio). If you have lots of clients, it might make sense to develop a setup program that does all those things for you.

Comment: @Calvinceokeyo: And yes, this is a lot of work and a lot of hassle. SQL Server is designed to be powerful database engine that can serve thousands of clients at the same time at high performance. If you don't *need* that power (especially since you mention that only the local PC will access that database), it might be more trouble than it's worth. We also did it in the past, but we switched to using SQLite for "local" databases, because it makes deployment **so much easier**.

Comment: :my problem with SQLCE and SQLite is that they may not support some of the aggregate functions eg COUNT and other things like DISTINCT,CASE WHEN.. and so on which my application depends on...How do I go about that..??

Comment: @Calvinceokeyo: Well, you make a list of the features you need (COUNT, DISTINCT, ...) and then check the SQLite docs...

Comment: Thank you for your generous support towards my predicament...Ok now let me check on SQLIte docs as per your advice...Last Question to you: Supposing I am using a named  SQL Server(EXPRESS) with name DATASQL on my machine, must I use the same name DATASQL with the SQL Server(EXPRESS) to be installed on the client's machine? Thank you so much @Heinzi

Comment: @Calvinceokeyo: Yes, if you want to hard-code the connection string. As others have mentioned, making the connection strong configurable has a lot of advantages, so you might want to consider doing that.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your assistance !